# Each day, a catalina.out file is empty (0 bytes). I restart tomcat and it refills. Next day, it is empty again

Tags: tomcat

A colleague left us, and I came on checking a `Tomcat` that has this strange behavior :
Each day, I find a `catalina.out` file in `logs` directory (owner `tomcat:tomcat`) having a size of 0 bytes.

I do a :
`systemctl restart tomcat.service`

and the `catalina.out` starts gaining contents then, while a `catalina.2019-11-14.log` is created aside, with some content too.

The next day, I find an empty `catalina.out` file again.
What can explain such behavior ? What should I check ?

Comment: Mis-configured `logrotate`, maybe?

Comment: We found that we had a mess with some logs having the tomcat group and others the root one. It helped but did not solved everything.